# Creating variables using $GLOBALS

Tags: php, frameworks, global-variables

I am currently working on a php framework, which is in some cases structured like the ZendFramework.
It has MVC etc.
*I did not found any equal matching to my problem.*

My "problem" is I have a variable number of classes (models, controller), e.g.
http_handler.
Now I have that much classes I can not set them all manualy into variables.

Can I use $GLOBALS to set a $variableVar?

```
foreach($classes as $class)
{   
    include_once($class . '.php');
    $GLOBALS[$class] = new $class;
}
```

Does this create a new variable which will be accessable through the whole code?
Example:

```
//... code
$http_handler->sendRequest($someArgs);
//... code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will, but you have to import the global variable in your method's scope:

```
function foo()
 {
  global $http_handler;
```

there are better solutions for this however. Check out the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for example.

I asked a question about how to organize all these classes recently aside from using the singleton pattern, maybe some of the answers give you additional ideas: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812472/in-a-php-project-how-do-you-organize-and-access-your-helper-objects)

Comment: Alright, thank you very much.
..but the singleton pattern still requires a variable to be assigned to ;)
I currently have some "main"objects containing singleton/factory instances of the "sub"objects of my framework.
$main->controllers->SpecificController->Method()
$main->model->User->SpecificModel->Method()

If I have a controller/model this huge syntax is wrapped to a simple one, also for security reasion:
$user = &$main->model->User

Comment: True, you have to assign a variable there as well, but a singleton approach still feels cleaner to me than working with globals and you can do exactly the same with a singleton as you can with a global object. Check out my question link, there are different solutions there that save assigning the variable - and a caveat that working this way is not really in the spirit of OOP, which is also important to note, no matter whether one lives by it or not.