# How to do OOP Based Web Design in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

How to do OOP Based Web Design in PHP?

May be you could link to me a post containing a tutorial or reference to Design Web in OOP Fashion?

Comment: OOP Based Web Design? For example, Defining a class for menu item then
it's entities would be link, alt, title and methods would be goToLink() etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to get a framework to help you with it. By far the most common pattern is [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), or MVC.

[Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707222/learning-php-oop)
[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059638/php-framework-oop-model)
[Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557691/good-training-sources-for-oop-php-anyone)

The last one has a good link to the [PHP manual guide to OOP.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you are beginner then I will suggest to read [The essentials of Object Oriented PHP](https://leanpub.com/the-essentials-of-object-oriented-php). 
You will get Clear concept of major OOP concepts with example. 
There are exercise section after each chapter and end of the book with solution too.

Also check this serious of Videos [PHP OOP Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL75B9D91CD69ED950)