# Combining multiple classes gives me errors in PHP?

Tags: php, class

I'm creating a website with structure like this:

```
class main { }

class mysql extends main { }

class user extends main { }

class etc extends main { }
```

The idea is for these classes to use functions from each other. This doesn't work. How can I call a function from `mysql` in `user`?

**EDIT:**
All errors are similar to this one:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method user::function_in_mysql() in C:\foo.php on line 8
```

Martti Laine

Comment: Do you know what classes are? Have you ever used them before?

Comment: well, it should work as long mysql is first class to load...
Can you write simple code?

Comment: Yea, I'm including files containing these classes, then I call them and use them. It gives me errors, when I try to call a function from mysql in user.

Comment: It may be a good idea to let us see those errors...

Comment: What you're (seemingly) trying to achieve results in strong dependencies between the classes. One way or another at least one class will have a "is-a" relation, while you want (at best) a "has-a" relation. Since your example classes are `user` and `mysql` (having a self-tailored mysql class is yet another issue imo) even dependency injection might be too "strong". see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling

Comment: @Martti check out my answer. I believe you're looking for something along the lines of dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a class extend another makes the methods of the other (parent) available to it. So `user` extending `main` only makes the methods of `main` available to it. If other classes extend `main` it doesn't allow all of them to call each others methods. You could have `user` extend `mysql` and `mysql`'s methods would then be available to `user` **though I don't believe that fundamentally this is what you're looking for**.

I think you're looking for something along the lines of dependency injection and not class inheritance.

For example if you wanted your user class to have access to your mysql class you pass it an instance of it in it's constructor.

```
class user {
    protected $_mysql;

    public function __construct(mysql $mysql) {
        $this->_mysql = $mysql;
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        $this->_mysql->myMysqlMethod();
    }
}

$mysql = new mysql();
$user = new user($mysql);

$user->myMethod();
```

Here's some good reading on dependency injection.

- [PHP Dependency Injection](http://www.potstuck.com/2009/01/08/php-dependency-injection/)
- [Symphony Dependency Injection](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/trunk/book/01-Dependency-Injection)

The Symphony link in particular is a pretty nice read on the overview of dependency injection and how to setup a dependency container.

Answer (score 2):

> The idea is for these classes to use functions from each other.

That's not what you're doing: Inheritance goes only one way. `mysql`, `user`, and `etc` inherit `main`s abilities but not those of each other.

You could have `mysql` extend `user` extend `etc` so that at least `mysql` can call all the functions but that probably won't make sense, as I think they are not ancestors but *siblings* to each other, fulfilling a distinctly different function.

You would have to either define any shared methods in `main` - often the best way to go - *or* introduce the classes to each other so they're able to call each other's functions. You could, for example, add an instance of each needed class as parameters to the constructor:

```
$etc = new etc();
$mysql = new mysql($etc);

// mysql's constructor sets $this->etc 
// so that it can call etc's functions using $this->etc->function()
```

or, more complex, using the dependency injection or singleton patterns. I asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812472/in-a-php-project-how-do-you-organize-and-access-your-helper-objects) some time ago about how to deal with this in PHP and got a lot of feedback, maybe it gives you some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

To call a function from `mysql` inside of `user` you could create an `mysql` object inside of `user` and call the function.

```
<?php
// this is user.php
$var = new mysql(); // <--if it takes parameters in the constructor
$var->method();
...
?>
```

For a better answer could you provide more information, as in, what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how extending a class works. All the functions that should exist in all classes should be part of main. Then functions that are specific to mysql go in that class. I'm guessing that the classes are not as closely linked in terms of inheritance as you think. If the user class needs to make calls through your mysql class, have a variable in the user class that holds a mysql object.