# PDO not working within function

Tags: php, function, pdo

I am trying to make a function to pull a page's content from a MySQL table using a PDO Prepare statement. My code works just fine outside of the function I defined, but no matter what I do it will not work within the function - I receive the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/tappess1/public_html/pages/stations.php on line 6**

Here is my PHP:

```
function getPageContent($page) {
        $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM content WHERE title LIKE ?");
        $st->execute(array($page));
        $pageContent = $st->fetch();
        $text = wordwrap($pageContent['content'], 100, "\n");
        $tabs = 4;
        $text = str_repeat(chr(9), $tabs) . str_replace(chr(10), chr(10) . str_repeat(chr(9), $tabs), $text);
        echo $text;
    }
```

and then

```
<?php getPageContent(Main);?>
```

I have even tried using a query instead of prepare statement, simply calling getPageContent() and I receive the same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to access the variable `$db` which is outside your function's [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Either re-initialize your database within the function `$db = new PDO....`, or - probably better and easier in your case - import the global variable:

```
function getPageContent($page) {
  global $db;
```

Where and how to best store the global database object is subject of a lot of discussion. If you want to get into it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812472/in-a-php-project-how-do-you-organize-and-access-your-helper-objects) is one place to start (there are many others on SO, too). But if you're just getting into PHP, I'd say using the global variable is fine.

Comment: It's amazing how fast questions are answered here. A light bulb went off in my head right after I posted and I realized what was going on, solved it by including the connection script to the function. Your solution is much better, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The variable $db is not known within your function.