# "superglobal object"

Tags: php

Using the following as an example (with $db being a previously created database connection object)...

```
Class Session {
   function write_log () {
     global $db;
     $db->query(...);
   }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having to write "global $db" everytime I want to use the $db object inside of another class?  In other words, declare the $db object as a superglobal from the very beginning.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812472/in-a-php-project-how-do-you-organize-and-access-your-helper-objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to access global objects (like Database or Log) from classes and scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967548/best-way-to-access-global-objects-like-database-or-log-from-classes-and-scripts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the `$db` to the class constructor:

```
class Session {
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function write_log () {
        $this->db->query(...);
    } 
}
```

And call it with:

```
$session = new Session($db);
```

Comment: That is the right way... using globals will make your code unreadable,unmaintainable and after some months or years unusable...

Answer (score 5):

[Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) are a specific set of built in variables provided by PHP that are accessible anywhere without having to be declared with `global`:

```
$GLOBALS
$_SERVER
$_GET
$_POST
$_FILES
$_COOKIE
$_SESSION
$_REQUEST
$_ENV
```

In general, is not possible to create your own superglobals.

You could however add a `$db` member to your `Session` class, and refer to `$this->db` instead:

```
class Session
{
   public $db;

   function __construct()
   {
     $this->db = ... // set up $db object
     // ...
   }

   function write_log ()
   {
     $this->db->query(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: It _is_ possible to create your own superglobals (http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.configuration.php) . One should however _never_ want to do that.

Comment: @Wrikken fair enough, I wasn't aware of that.