# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare()

Tags: php, pdo, prepare

I've been looking at this code for ages now and I cant really understand what it want from me. I keep getting the same error message no matter what I try and I've looked through other threads to no avail. The error is **Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\new_serverside\sprint1.php on line 63**. my code is :

```
<?php 
    include 'ConfigDB.php';
?>

            <?php
             if(getConnection())
                {
                    echo "Server connection successful";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Problem with connection";
                }


            ini_set('display_errors', 1);

            global $dbh;

            $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM faculty"); 
            $query->execute();
            $result = $dbh->query($query);


            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                echo $row['Name'] . "<br/>"; 
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Looks like `$dbh` is not really defined to what you think it is. Use `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error sounds like `$dbh` hasn't initialized properly. You can make sure that won't happen in the future by using a [singleton class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instead of a global variable.

```
class DB {
    private $instance = NULL;
    private __construct() {
        // create an instance of your db handler
    }
    public static getInstance() {
        if (!$this->instance)
            $this->instance = new DB();
        return $this->instance;
    }
}
```

And use it in your code like this

```
$dbh = DB::getInstance();
```

Comment: For anyone else who finds this, Singletons are a different kind of global is all. [Singletons are not considered a good design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812472/in-a-php-project-what-patterns-exist-to-store-access-and-organize-helper-objec)

Answer (score 0):

Call var_dump() on $dbh just after the global reference.

```
var_dump($dbh);
```

You should find something in there that isn't what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, its fixed that problem. Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `$dbh` isn't an object, so you can't call the `prepare()` method on it. Where is `$dbh` initialized? Try doing `var_dump($dbh);` before calling `prepare()` to see what's really in that variable.